# math : template specialization =0 for any other classes

Tags: templates, math, specialization, levels

I explain my problem. I want to code math with template general thing. So far I've made two classes. I have a

```
template<typename T> class rational{
    T numerator;
    T denominator;
    operators and constructors
}
```

And I have a

```
template<typename T> class polynomial{
    vector<T> coefficients;
    int degree;
    operators and constuctors
}
```

these are made so that I can use `rational<polynomial<rational<int>>>` . This works so far. But I want to add a Derivative on those class. I want to define it on the `class<T>` using it's definition on T too. This can be made. But how can I make this Derivative be =0 on int, on double, on `fractional<int>`, etc ? It's like a specialization, but for every type which I didn't specifie ... Thanks ! After this, I try to template the matrix thing ...

the goal is to go as far as possible with templates :-D
Next I want to use several variables for polynomial ... It's a great projet !

Thanks for any help / any information =)

I think **answer would be like** :

```
template<typename T> T Derivative(T object){ // for any other object !
return T(0);}

template<typename T> polynomial<T> Derivative(polynomial<T> object)
return compute_of_derivative, using too Derivative over T too (for generality);}

template<typename T> rational<T> Derivative(rational<T> object) // kind P / Q
return compute_of_derivative, which is ( D(P)Q -Q D(P) /  Q^2 );}
```

is this working ? :-/ I will try it soon ...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: https://github.com/mwameme/template-math Here is the total code. Which part are you interested in ? it's basic math (polynomial, fraction, GCD( x,y ), multiplication etc ...)

Comment: If you're looking for an answer to your question, you should condense your code such that the problem for which you asked for help becomes obvious.

Comment: I want to define a function Derivative that returns 0 everytime, but I want my derivative to return something computed for the class `polynomial<T>` and for the class `fractional<T>`. That's my only problem now. Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to define a function Derivative that returns 0 everytime, but I
> want my derivative to return something computed for the class
> polynomial and for the class fractional. That's my only problem
> now.

You can do that by overloading the derivative function:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T> struct polynomial{};
template<typename T> struct rational{};

template<typename T>
auto derivative(T t) {  std::cout<<"I'm zero"<<std::endl;  }

template<typename T>
auto derivative(rational<T> t) { std::cout<<"I'm a rational number"<<std::endl; }

template<typename T>
auto derivative(polynomial<T> t) { std::cout<<"I'm a polynomial"<<std::endl; }

int main()
{
    derivative(rational<double>{});
    derivative(polynomial<double>{});
    derivative(int{});
}
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f49beb031f5859d)

Comment: Thanks, perfect ! I have no time to code now, but soon I check it =) cool !
I find it funny to use template this way =) for training and fun

Comment: it does ! I think I did accept it